# Google Chrome stable libdrm2 unmet dependencies issue

Tags: google-chrome, dependencies, docker

I'm trying to install Google Chrome stable on Ubuntu 18.04 with a Dockerfile. Previously it has always worked as expected but since today I receive dependency errors about `libdrm2`.

Error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.60) but 2.4.58-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Related code in Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y \
        apt-transport-https \
        gnupg \
        --no-install-recommends &&\
  curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - &&\
  echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list &&\
  apt-get update &&\
  apt-get install -y \
      google-chrome-stable \
      --no-install-recommends
```

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I'm not sure how I can solve this problem. Things I've tried without success:

- Run apt-get -f install google-chrome-stable (-f stands for --fix-broken)
- Run docker-compose with --no-cache (thought it could be related to cache)

Hope anyone can put me in the right direction!

Comment: Please be awre that 18.04 has only days of support left.

Comment: @Alvin Vogelzang, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem.
What works for me is configuration from https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker.
I guess the problem is old version of NODE.

Comment: @Quark no unfortunately not. Thanks Jonasjonny. Will check that out!

Comment: @jonasjonny What you suggested was close to what worked for me. Instead of installing the packages separately with 14-slim, I used 14.20.0 base image and it resolved the issue for me. Thanks!